# How to label the row the way iPhone built in alarm app labeled its alarm name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I want to label the row just like the way iPhone alarm app label's its alarm name. I don't want a back button. I just want to pass whatever text I input to be passed to the `MainViewController`.

I am using delegate, but I am not quite sure where to put my delegate code in my ViewController which has my texfield. I have 2 ViewControllers connected with "show" segue. One has table row and another has textfield.

Code below:

*second.h* (where textfield is)

```
@protocol LabelNameDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)LabelNameEntered:(NSString*)labelName;
@end

@property(nonatomic, weak) id<LabelNameDelegate> delegate;
```

*second.m*

```
 [self.delegate LabelNameEntered:self.myLabel.text];(not sure where to place it exactly)
```

*first.h*

```
 @interface FirstTableViewController : UITableViewController<LabelNameDelegate>
```

*first.m*

```
  - (void)LabelNameEntered:(NSString*)labelName{
NSLog(@"This is text from secondview: %@", labelName);
}
```

Comment: I think you should save all "alarms" someqhere (nsuserdefauilts or core data), update it in detail controller and in list controller reload data on viewWillAppear. It's if I correctly understood what do you want.

Comment: @VladislavKovalyov If you set up the new alarm on your iphone, you have an option to set the alarm name. I just want to know how this functionality is coded. I have a table row in first viewcontroller and textfield on the second viewcontroller, they are connected with "show" segue.

Comment: "I am using delegate, but I am not quite sure where to put my delegate code in in my viewcontroller where my textfield is."  You can put your delegate methods anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed my delegate code in the following method, it worked perfectly. The following code means, once `second viewController` is closed, pass following value to the `first viewController`.

**second.m**

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.delegate LabelNameEntered:self.myLabel.text];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to accomplish this task, I'd create a delegate protocol in my textfield view controller's .h file, then create methods that my textfield view controller could call to let the delegate - which would be the table view's view controller - know what the user entered in the text  field.

Edit:  This page should help you figure out how to create your own delegate protocol: [How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

Edit:  If you tried this and can't get it to work, please post some code so we can help you.

Comment: I added some code. Could you please look at them and give me a advise?

Answer (score 0):

In the *second.m* implement

[- textFieldDidBeginEditing:](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidBeginEditing:)

So whenever the textField is done editing, you can call the delegate you have

**Note** I am not sure why you have a label here, shouldn't it be textfield?

```
[self.delegate LabelNameEntered:self.myLabel.text];
```